# Graphics card issue

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, overheating

Today I decided to do a little cleaning, so I went and used compressed air to clear the dust in my PC. After connecting it back up it started up normally so I stepped away for a bit. When I came back the PC was turned off and I couldn't start it and there was a faint smell as if something has burnt. First I thought my PSU went so I replaced it with one from another PC to check, but it still didn't start. Then I did a quick google search and decided to try disconnecting my Graphics card. It worked. Now I can start up the PC, I even replaced the card with an ancient one so I can use my PC ( abit at a low resolution  since there are no WIN10 drivers for a 15 years old card ).

Anyway my questions are

- Can I somehow bring my graphics card back to life? I've read
  somewhere that you can repair it by putting it in an oven for a few
  min? How does that work?
- Any other fixes I can try? or at least a way to determine what the issue was.

p.p.: My specs are ( or rather were )

Gigabyte EP43-UD3L

Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 @ 2.66GHz

4,00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 399MHz

Gigabyte GeForce GTS 250 1GB

Comment: It's difficult to say if you can restore functionality to this GPU if you can't tell us whats wrong with it.

Comment: "What new alternative cards do you suggest?" - **Hardware recomendations** are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: If it were me, and I had just fried a GPU on a six year old motherboard for unknown reasons, I would not go out and buy a brand new GPU and put it into that same motherboard. Risk isn't super high but motherboards are not very expensive.

Comment: "I've read somewhere that you can repair it by putting it in an oven for a few min?" - **This helps in specific situations**, it also isn't a sure thing, even when that situation applies to your siutation.  In this case, it does not, apply to your situation putting your card in the oven won't fix it.

Comment: @Ramhound since the GPU is dead I can't really tell you whats wrong with it. I didn't know hardware recommendations are not a topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JaredT I haven't had any issues prior to today, and maybe I did something with the compressed air to hurt the GPU ( blew a chunk of dust into the fan so it got blocked? ). Anyway I plan to buy a new PC or upgrade this one when I get the budget, until then I need a new GPU since I need the PC functional.

Comment: @stillan00b - You should read our help center so you understand what type of questions are on topic.  You should also edit your question so it is within our scope, you can make that modification, and it won't effect the usefullness of the answers you have recieved so far.

Comment: Blowing air directly at the fans in your PC is NEVER a good idea. The fans are usually very delicately balanced and the force of the canned air can either spin them faster than they are designed to go or move them out of their very close tolerances. Either way, the chance for damage is quite high. In the future, use a pin or stick to hold the fan blades still or to allow them on only spin slowly while blowing them out, and use only short blasts of air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you smell burning, it may have been a capacitor on your GPU that burned up, in that case the card is likely done.

1. Doubtful that putting it in the oven will repair it. What the "oven trick" attempts to do is melt the solder on the silicon board in a effort to "fix" any cracked solder points. Even if solder points were your issue, I really doubt this would help you.
2. Most any card around $80-$100 or so is going to be at least an upgrade from your toasted one.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

1.) No. If you are smelling burned components, then you will not be able to stick it in the oven and revive it. I would also suggest never sticking electronic components in the oven unless you fully understand why you are doing it and knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish.You could in theory take the card apart, test each component, and solder them back on and replace the burnt out components. But.. no one has time for that.

2) Really its up to you. I have a r9 270x 4Gb GDDR3 and i play battlefield one on ultra and rarely drop below 60fps. 
However, I am not here to tell you what to buy. My suggestion is to do the research for what will work for you and how much you want to spend.

On a side note, you may want want to start a budget and slowly upgrade your system all together.

Comment: Thank you! Starting a budget was in the back of my mind for years, I guess it's about time to start one.